# How to find correct position to insert an element in a sorted array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have to make a program in Java to create a sorted array in descending order. When i try to insert 10, 3 it is ok, but when i insert 10, 3, 8 the result is 10, 8, 0. For some reason the 0 appears on the end. Also when i try to imput negative numbers like -2 the result becomes -2, 8, 0. Can someone help? Also, is bubble sort the correct method for this kind of insertion? (Sorry for my english it is my first time here). Thank you for your time.

```
    private int searchPosition(int a)
    {
        int position = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {
            if(array[i] != a)
            {
                if((array[i] > a) && (array[i + 1] < a))
                {
                    position = i + 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                position = i;
            }
        }

        return position;
    }

    public boolean insert(int a)
    {
        int position;
        boolean exists;
        int temp;

        if (size == capacity)
        {
            System.out.println("The array is full.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            exists = //here i call a method to make sure the element to insert doesn't exist in the array

            if (exists == false)
            {
                //Bubble Sort in desceding order
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                {
                    for (int j=0; j < array.length() - i; j++)
                    {
                        if (array[j] < array[j + 1])
                        {
                            temp = array[j + 1];
                            array[j + 1] = array[j];
                            array[j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }
                position = searchPosition(a);
                //move elements one position to the right
                for (int i = array.length(); i < position; i--)
                {
                    array[i] = array[i - 1];
                }
                array[position] = a;
                //place a in the free position
                size++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The element" + a + " already exists in the array.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Attach a debugger, step through the code. This is how you learn.

Comment: i debugged it and the result is this 
        10 3 
        Insert 8
        The array is: 
        10 8 0

Comment: Binary Search on array for 1+elem. Index for insertion is the position before the result. Then shift the array and insert the elem.

Comment: @flower I fail to see what bubble sort has to do with it. Since you are saying  you have to create a sorted array in descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `break` statement, where you exit the loop when a value is smaller then a value in the array and use this index.

```
int value = 8;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] < value) {
        break;
    }
}

for(int j = array.length; j > i; j--) {
    a[j] = a[j -1];
}
a[j] = value;
size++;
```